# Unable to run Pi example for Apache Spark from Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I've setup my first spark cluster (1 master, 2 workers) and an iPython notebook server that I've setup to access the cluster. I'm running the workers from Anaconda to make sure the python setup is correct on each box. The iPy notebook server appears to have everything setup correctly, and I'm able to initialize Spark and push a job out. However, the job is failing, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot. Here's the code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from numpy import random
CLUSTER_URL = 'spark://192.168.1.20:7077'
sc = SparkContext( CLUSTER_URL, 'pyspark')
def sample(p):
    from numpy import random
    x, y = random(), random()
    return 1 if x*x + y*y < 1 else 0

count = sc.parallelize(xrange(0, 20)).map(sample).reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
print "Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / 20)
```

And here's the error:

> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         3     return 1 if x*x + y*y < 1 else 0
>         4 
>   ----> 5 count = sc.parallelize(xrange(0, 20)).map(sample).reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
>         6 print "Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / 20)
>
> /opt/spark-1.2.0/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in reduce(self, f)
>       713             yield reduce(f, iterator, initial)
>       714 
>   --> 715         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
>       716         if vals:
>       717             return reduce(f, vals)
>
> /opt/spark-1.2.0/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in collect(self)
>       674         """
>       675         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
>   --> 676             bytesInJava = self._jrdd.collect().iterator()
>       677         return list(self._collect_iterator_through_file(bytesInJava))
>       678
>
> /opt/spark-1.2.0/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
>   in **call**(self, *args)
>       536         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
>       537         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
>   --> 538                 self.target_id, self.name)
>       539 
>       540         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> /opt/spark-1.2.0/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in
>   get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
>   --> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
>       301             else:
>       302                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.collect. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 31 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   31.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 72, 192.168.1.21): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "/opt/spark-1.2.0/python/pyspark/worker.py", line
>   107, in main
>       process()   File "/opt/spark-1.2.0/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)   File "/opt/spark-1.2.0/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 227, in
>   dump_stream
>       vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))   File "/opt/spark-1.2.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 710, in func
>       initial = next(iterator)   File "", line 2, in sample TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.(PythonRDD.scala:174)
>     at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:96)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1214)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
>     at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor.aroundReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1375)
>     at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)     at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)  at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)   at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)  at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

I'm not even sure where to start debugging / diagnosing this, so any help would be appreciated. Happy to post other logs if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numpy.random` is a Python package, you can't call it using `random()`.

I guess you wanted to use `random.random()`, here the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html#numpy.random.random).

Comment: @Dave - It's buried in the trace, but the relevant error snippet is: `File "/opt/spark-1.2.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 710, in func initial = next(iterator) File "", line 2, in sample TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`